# How do I build a dynamic SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Right, so I have a set of dropdowns on my page. Depending on whether a value is selected, I want to add it to an SQL query string in PHP. Example:

```
select1: options("*" "op1", "op2)
select2: options("*" "op1", "op2)
select3: options("*" "op1", "op2)
```

'*' refers to anything. i.e the data should not be filtered by that query option. Now, how do I build the query for this quickly and simply? Currently, I have something like this:

```
$query='';
$found=0;
$op1=$_POST['select1'];
$op2=$_POST['select2'];
$op3=$_POST['select3'];

if($op1!='*')
{
$found=1;
$op1="'".$op1."'";
$query="WHERE op1=$op1 ";

}

if($op2!='*')
{$op2="'".$op2."'";
if($found==1)
    {
    $query=$query. "AND op2=$op2 ";
    }
else{
    $found=1;
    $query="WHERE op2=$op2 ";
    }
}

if($op3!='*')
{$op3="'".$op3."'";
if($found==1)
    {
    $query=$query. "AND op3=$op3 ";
    }
else{
    $found=1;
    $query="WHERE op3=$op3 ";
    }
}
```

Now, obviously, this is quite annoying to implement. Is there any easier method?

Thanks.

Comment: Be warned that the current code exposes you to SQL injection attacks.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Gaby - I'm quite aware. This is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have used a class MyQueryBuilder with following methods probably..

```
AddSelectionColumn(String ColumnName, string Alias)
AddTableSource(String TableName, String Alias)
AddTableJoin(String Table1, String Alias1, String Table2, String Alias2, String Col1, String Col2, JoinType Join)
AddFilterCondition(String ColumnName, String Alias, String Condition)
```

It might give a better control on the code...

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of this in my perl CGI scripts, and this is how I format it for simplicity / readability:

First, I use a separate variable for the where clause, and always set a condition of
1 = 1 so all subsequent conditions are "and" conditions:

```
my $whereClause      =<<ENDWHERESQL;
where
   1 = 1
ENDWHERESQL

if ( $op1 ne "*" )    { $whereClause .= "     and op1 = '".safeSQL($op1)."'\n"; }
if ( $op2 ne "*" )    { $whereClause .= "     and op2 = '".safeSQL($op2)."'\n"; }
if ( $op3 ne "*" )    { $whereClause .= "     and op3 = '".safeSQL($op3)."'\n"; }
```

then I use a simple function to protect against simple SQL injection attacks, because even though you are using drop down lists - someone could still put a "?op1=(evil sql)" on the end of your URL, and it might get through your form into your query:

```
#******************************************************************************
# Function: safeSQL()
#   Author: Ron Savage
#     Date: 04/22/2009
# 
# Description:
# This removes update,create,drop,deletes from SQL.
#******************************************************************************
sub safeSQL
   {
   my $cmd;
   my ( $inText,$commandList ) = @_;

   if (!defined($commandList)) { $commandList = "create,delete,select,update,dele,drop,exec,insert"; }

   foreach $cmd (split(/\,/,$commandList))
      {
      $inText =~ s/ $cmd |^$cmd /** no_${cmd}_allowed! **/gi;
      }

   return($inText);
   }
```